# Is it possible to configure applications to use different network interfaces differently? If yes, how?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bonding

I am running [scrapy](http://scrapy.org) on ubuntu server 13. And while it is crawling the network becomes very slow and it becomes difficult to even ssh into the system.

I think I can solve the problem by having one more network interface card connected to a different router that scrapy doesn't use. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, yes. A few notes that might be useful:

1. If you have more than one interface, you can set up static routes that specify which interface should be used to get to a specific destination. [CentOS networking docs](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html) have a decent guide. That lets you specify what interface the system uses to get to a specific outbound address.
2. It sounds more like you want to be able to get *in* on an alternate interface. Most daemons, like `ssh`, let you configure which interface they listen on. For ssh, see the [sshd_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) `ListenAddress` configuration.
3. Neither of those were you actual question, of course, which was if it was possible to configure an application to use a specific interface. That's also possible, if you use the [iptables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) `--uid-owner` option to specify a route that's only used by apps from that user. There's [a useful discussion of this scenario on linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/per-application-routing-538288) .
4. Finally, are you sure you're network bottlenecked? If you can't even get a prompt, I'd check to make sure `scrapy` isn't consuming too much CPU, and consider `nice`-ing it etc. if so.